# register page...doesn't work properly

Tags: php, mysql

i got my register page but when the submit button is pressed it doesn't carry out the checks that it should. instead it misses them all out for some strange reason and returns the page with no error text.

```
<?php
require "PasswordHash.php";
require "header.php";
require "globe.php";


echo "<body>
<div class='container'>";
echo "<div class='centered'>
      <ul id='nav'>
       <li><a href='login.php'>Home </a></li>
       <li><a href='register.php'>Register</a></li>
       <li><a href='forgotpassword.php'>Forgot Password</a></li>
       <li><a href='contact.php'>Contact</a></li>
       <li><a href='t&c.php'>Terms and Conditions</a></li>
      </ul>";
echo"
<img src='banner1.jpg' width='800px' height='200px' />

 <div class='regban'>
   <img src='outsideimage/registertop.png' width='800px' height='40px' />
 </div>



<div class='registertext'>
Registiring to Zone Wars allows you to be that one step closer to being part of our fantastic community! Simply register for free and with our quick registration form you will be playing very soon! <br />
<font color='red'><i>Please note registration is not currently taking place due to large maintenance. We are sorry for any inconvenience this may have caused. </i></font>";
$regsec = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

if (isset($_POST['register'])) 
{ 
    $user = trim($_POST['user']);
    $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
    $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $error_string = '';
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = "HIDDEN AS ITS PRIVATE";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);
    $hash_cost_log2 = 8;
    $hash_portable = FALSE;
    $hasher = new PasswordHash($hash_cost_log2, $hash_portable);




    function isValidEmail($email = '')
    {
    return preg_match("/^[\d\w\/+!=#|$?%{^&}*`'~-][\d\w\/\.+!=#|$?%{^&}*`'~-]*@[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9.-]{1,61}[A-Z0-9]\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/ix",$email);
    }

    $userrow = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE username = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $user) . "'");
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($userrow);

    $emailrow = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE email = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $email) . "'");
    $row_cnt1 = mysqli_num_rows($emailrow);


     if (!$resp->is_valid) {
                  $error_string .= '<center>The reCAPTCHA wasnt entered correctly. Go back and try it again.</center><br />';
        }
    else if ($user == '') {
    $error_string .= '<center>You left the Username field blank!.</center><br />';
    }
    else if (strlen($user) < 4) {
    $error_string .= '<center>Your Username must be at least 4 characters long.</center><br />';
    }
    else if (strlen($user) > 8) {
    $error_string .= '<center>You Username cannot be longer then 8 characters.</center><br />';
    }
    else if ( !preg_match("/^[a-z]+[\w.-]*$/i", $user) ) {
    $error_string .='<center>Your username may only contain letters, numbers, dots, underscores, hyphen and start with a letter</center>';
    }
    else if ($row_cnt != 0) {
    $error_string .= '<center>Your Username exists</center><br />';
    }
    else if ($pass1 == '')
    {
    $error_string .='<center>You left the password field blank.<br /></center>';
    }
    else if ($pass2 == '') {
    $error_string .='<center>You left the confirmation password blank<br /></center>';
    }
    else if ($pass1 != $pass2) {
    $error_string .='<center>Your password and confirmation password do not match<br /></center>';
    }
    else if(strlen($pass1) > 72) {
    $error_string .='<center>Your password cannot be longer then 72 characters<br /></center>';
    }
    else if ($email == '') {
    $error_string .='<center>You left the email field blank!.<br /></center>';
    }
    else if ($email != $email2) {
    $error_string .='<center>Your email and confirmation email did not match.<br /></center>';
    }
    else if (!isValidEmail($email)) {
    $error_string .= '<center>Please enter a valid email address.<br></center>';
    }
    else if ($row_cnt1 != 0) {
    $error_string .= '<center>Your email address exists</center><br />';
    }
    else {

        if ($error_string != '') {
            echo "<font color=red> '$error_string' </font><br /><center> Please go back and fix the errors <a href=register.php>here</a></center>";
        }
        else {
        $hash = $hasher->HashPassword($pass1);
        get_post_var($user);
        get_post_var($email);
        $euser = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $user);
        $eemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $email);


            if (strlen($hash) >= 20) {
         mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO Persons (Username, Password, Email, Gender) VALUES ('$euser', '$hash', '$eemail', '$gender')");
         echo "You have signed up to the game! Please login <a href='login.php'here</a>. ";
            }
            else
            {
            echo "<center>A fatal error occured. Please contact the Admin board</center><br />";
        }
        }
             }
}
else
{ 

    echo "
    <form action='$regsec' method='POST'>
    <table align='center' border='0'>
    <tr><td align='right'>Username:</td><td><input type='text' name='user'  /></td></tr>
    <tr><td align='right'>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='pass1' /></td></tr>
    <tr><td align='right'>Confirm Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='pass2' /></td></tr>
    <tr><td align='right'>Email Address:</td><td><input type='text' name='email' /></td></tr>
    <tr><td align='right'>Confirm Email Address:</td><td><input type='text' name='email2' /></td></tr>
    <tr><td align='right'>Gender:</td><td><select name='gender'><option value='Male'>Male</option><option value='Female'>Female</option></select></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'><center>";
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $publickey = "HIDDEN AS ITS PRIVATE"; // you got this from the signup page
    echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
    echo "</center></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'><center>By registring you have read and agreed our <a href='t&c.php'>Terms and Conditions</a></center></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'><center><input type='submit' name='register' value='register'></center></td><td></td></tr>
    </table></form>";
}
echo "</div>

<img src='outsideimage/registerbott.png' width='800px' height='20px' />
</div>";



echo "&nbsp;<br />
<div class='image'>
  <img alt='' src='outsideimage/bottom.png' />
  <div class='text'>
    <small>Copyright &copy; 2012  All Rights Reserved.</small>
  </div>
  <div class='text1'>
    <small>";
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
echo "</small>
  </div>
</div>
</body>";
?>
```

Comment: try printing out the content of $_POST using print_r($_POST) to see what is being sent

Comment: mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO Persons (Username, Password, Email, Gender) VALUES ('$euser', '$hash', '$eemail', '$gender')"); you are not escaping $gender anywhere in your code so SQL Injection is possible. Just thought you should know =o)

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting any error messages because you are not printing it out. You assign your error messages to variable $error_string, but there's no where in the code where it prints it out. Try putting an echo after your last else statement.

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) {
  ...
}
else if ($user == '') {
  ...
}
else if (strlen($user) < 4) {
  ...
}
...
else {
  ...
}
echo $error_string;
```

Also, seems like the last else in your validation seems unnecessary since you're checking if $error_string is empty or not.

Comment: if ($error_string != '') {
            echo "<font color=red> '$error_string' </font><br /><center> Please go back and fix the errors <a href=register.php>here</a></center>";
        }

isnt being displayed there